# Ruby on rails. Paperclip mp3 validation failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, mp3

Ok, I am allowing users to upload mp3's. Now for some reason only some mp3 files will upload and others will not. I cannot find any distinguishable difference between the working and non working files.

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_attached_file :audio, :restricted_characters => /[&$+,\/:;=?@<>\[\]\{\}\|\\\^~%#]/, dependent: :destroy
  validates_attachment_presence :audio
  validates_attachment_content_type :audio, :content_type => [ 'audio/mpeg', 'audio/mp3' ]
  validates_attachment_size :audio, :less_than => 20.megabytes
end
```

The server output for failing files is;

```
Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/acf7bcfce06ffcaa55511087ea2e486f20160427-7322-y1lyj6.mp3'
[paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename leyinnata.mp3 (audio/mp3 from Headers, ["audio/mpeg"] from Extension), content type discovered from file command: application/octet-stream. See documentation to allow this combination.
```

So the file is being seen as `application/octet-stream` instead of `audio/mp3` and I don't know why.

I heeded to the suggestion of reading the documentation and found a possible solution:

paperclip.rb

```
Paperclip.options[:content_type_mappings] = {
  :audio=> 'application/octet-stream'
}
```

this does nothing. (I restarted the server)

I cannot understand why it won't work and I am now getting very frustrated. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

UPDATE:

Specifying more audio file types doesn't seem to make any difference.

```
validates_attachment_content_type :audio, :content_type => [ 'audio/mpeg', 'audio/x-mpeg', 'audio/mp3', 'audio/x-mp3', 'audio/mpeg3', 'audio/x-mpeg3', 'audio/mpg', 'audio/x-mpg', 'audio/x-mpegaudio' ]
```

I have also tried adding `application/octet-stream` to `validates_attachment_content_type`
eg.

```
validates_attachment_content_type :audio, :content_type => [ 'application/octet-stream', 'audio/mpeg', 'audio/x-mpeg', 'audio/mp3', 'audio/x-mp3', 'audio/mpeg3', 'audio/x-mpeg3', 'audio/mpg', 'audio/x-mpg', 'audio/x-mpegaudio' ]
```

No luck.

I saw someone add

```
Paperclip.options[:content_type_mappings] = {
  audio: "application/octet-stream"
}
```

to their environment.rb files. This doesn't work for me either.

UPDATE 2:

In paperclip.rb, adding:

```
module Paperclip
  # do not require any validations
  REQUIRED_VALIDATORS = []

  # do not complain when missing validations
  class Attachment
    def missing_required_validator?
      false
    end
  end

  # skip media type spoof detection
  module Validators
    class MediaTypeSpoofDetectionValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
      def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
        true
      end
    end
  end
end
```

lets me upload what I need, but this skips spoofing validations and I imagine could be dangerous. My users are also allowed to upload images in a separate part of the website and I know that I would now be vunerable to attacks.

UPDATE 3:

I have added

```
module Paperclip
  class MediaTypeSpoofDetector
    def spoofed?
      false
    end
  end
end
```

to my `paperclip.rb`. This seems to be working ok. If anyone can come up with  better solution then I'd love to hear it otherwise I'll answer my own question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved it by removing everything that I put in the 'updates' and adding:

```
Paperclip.options[:content_type_mappings] = {
  mp3: 'application/octet-stream'
}
```

to `paperclip.rb`

Comment: Worked! Also Rails4 with paperclip 4.x

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to become more specific with mp3 types validations .
Like an example ,

You should

```
validates_content_type :audio :content_type => [ 'audio/mpeg', 'audio/x-mpeg', 'audio/mp3', 'audio/x-mp3', 'audio/mpeg3', 'audio/x-mpeg3', 'audio/mpg', 'audio/x-mpg', 'audio/x-mpegaudio' ]
```

Hope this will solve your problem . Please let us know.

Comment: Hey, thanks the reply but it doesn't help. I get the exact same result.